# Why is my app crashing when loading my in app purchases?

Tags: xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

I have this code that loads my in app purchases in the didMoveToView. If I press a button to go to my help screen or another button to leave the scene before the in app purchases load the app crashes. I think Im calling it in the wrong place. Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong? If you need more code or info let me know please. Thanks!

```
     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "unlockLevelTwo", "unlockLevelThree", "unlockEverything")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1**
Did you add the `StoreKit` framework to your project?

**#2**
Make sure not to release the class containing the corresponding methods at the end.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: the in app purchases work perfectly...its just that the if statment is being called everytime I go back to the gameScene even when Im not purchasing the product. When I go to a different scene and the in app purchases don't load it crashes my app. I want to call it once I want to purchase the in app purchase not when I open my app or leave the gameScene or come back to it.

Comment: That is what is causing my app to crash.